# How to send big html emails faster with phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a server that is sending emails for a client, 5000 per minute :)
I have 10 vps's set up only with php and a mailserver. On each vps there are 10 cronjobs that send 50 mails each. They take emails from a queue in mysql from another server and put the emails to send in it's own vps.

All good so far. It works perfectly when emails that are sent have a small html code like max 400-500 tows of code. One cronjob snd 50 emails like these in about 30 seconds. Cronjobs run every minute so in order to not creat overload, if the cronjob does not finish within one minute it kills itself and places the emails not sent back in queue. So the next cronjob continues where the other one left.

My problem is that big emails with 1000 or 2000 rows of html code take much much longer to be sent. For example a 4-500 rows email is sent in 0.5-0.8 seconds so the cronjob finishes sending 50 emails in less then a minute, but a 1000+ rows email get sent in about 2sec, so the cronjob never can finish sending 50 in one minute.

The problem is that the server sends a normail campaign with 5000 emails per minute, but a big html emails campaign with no more than 2000-3000 emails per minute. And this means half the speed.

Does anybody know a solution for making big html emails be sent faster?

I am using php 5.13, phpmailer and a 8 core 3.4 Ghz server with ssd hardware.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know a solution for making big html emails be sent faster?

The right question is *"what takes so much time when sending emails?"*. If you answer this, it will be easier to answer *"how to send emails faster?"*.

So, install [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or [`xhprof`](http://php.net/xhprof), profile your code, see what takes so much time, optimize, win.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said in my question, i know for a fact that bigger html emails take longer to send. I asked if there is anything I can do to improve the time that long html emails take to be sent.

Comment: Can you tell what takes so much time ? (is the time taken by phpmailer for encoding the email before sending ? is the time taken by data transfers ? something else ?)

Comment: Phpmailer seems to be the problem. First i thought the problem was because i requested the template file for every single email that is beeing sent, but then i made the template load only once per runtime. So if i have 50 emails to send but all of them use the same template i only load the template once in a variable. If there are overall 2 templates to be sent i only load each of them once. This temporary solution improved the overall runtime of the cron by 2-3 seconds, but each email keeps taking to much to load inside phpmailer before sending it to the mailserver... Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi! I did exactly as you said. Phpmailer takes too much time to process the html I send to it. What to do? :)